# Convert FileInfo read file code to maui equivalent

Tags: file, .net-6.0, .net-maui

I know I should know how to do this, but I don't.

I have some code (from a brilliant map routing packing called Itinero http://docs.itinero.tech/index.html) that reads in a a routerDb file.

It works great (in windows) if I use a fully qualified path as it is absolute, but I have moved the file into the Resources.Raw folder and want to  read it properly.

The working code

```
    using (var stream = new FileInfo(@"/path/to/my/file/gb.routerdb").OpenRead())
    {
      routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

How can I use the Maui approach to do the same thing? Such as or simpler

```
    using (var stream = new xxx("gb.routerdb").xxxx)
    {
      routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

I'm looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows but I don't get it :(

Thanks for any help.

G.

Answer (score 1):

As document [Platform differences of File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#platform-differences) mentioned, you can use method `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync` to access file in the `Resources\Raw` folder as a `MauiAsset`.

Besides, if you want to access the path of the items in folder `Raw`, you can follow up the unknown issue about this:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7943 .

**Update：**

As a test, I created a simple html(`test.html`) in folder `Resource\Raw`, and set `BuildAction` to `MauiAsset`.And I used the following code to read the html, it works well on my side(I tested on android device).

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task InitAsync()
    {
        string filePath = "test.html";
#if WINDOWS
            var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Assets/" + filePath);
#else
        var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);
#endif

        if (stream != null)
        {
            string s = (new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
            this.MyWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = s };
        }
    }

    private void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitAsync();

    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml`

```
    <VerticalStackLayout 
        Spacing="25" 
        Padding="30,0" 
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <WebView   x:Name="MyWebView"
            />

        <Button 
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: Example code as per above perhaps. As I said I didn't understand the docs.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part of my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well I certainly appreciate the example code, but for some reason it didn't work for me, but what did work based on your code (@Jessie Zhang) was:

```
    var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("gb.routerdb");

    if (stream != null)
    {
      routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

The conditional didn't work and I'm not sure why, but I'm only using windows so I'll check that out later. Thanks

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?